# RegEx for matching specific URLs

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to write a regex in python that that will either match a URL (for example https://www.foo.com/) or a domain that starts with "sc-domain:" but doesn't not have https or a path.

For example, the below entries should pass

```
https://www.foo.com/
https://www.foo.com/bar/
sc-domain:www.foo.com
```

However the below entries should fail

```
htps://www.foo.com/
https:/www.foo.com/bar/
sc-domain:www.foo.com/
sc-domain:www.foo.com/bar
scdomain:www.foo.com
```

Right now I'm working with the below:

```
^(https://*/|sc-domain:^[^/]*$)
```

This almost works, but still allows submissions like sc-domain:www.foo.com/ to go through. Specifically, the `^[^/]*$` part doesn't capture that a '/' should not pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^((?:https://\S+)|(?:sc-domain:[^/\s]+))$
```

You can try this.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xXSayK/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
^(?:https?://www\.foo\.com(?:/\S*)*|sc-domain:www\.foo\.com)$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of line
- `(?:` - Start of non-group for alternation
- `https?://www\.foo\.com(?:/\S*)*` - This matches a URL starting with http:// or https:// followed by www.foo.com and further optionally followed by path using
- `|` - alternation for strings starting with sc-domain:
- `sc-domain:www\.foo\.com` - This part starts matching with sc-domain: followed by www.foo.com and further does not allow any file path
- `)$` - Close of non-grouping pattern and end of string.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxmPum/1)**

Also, a little not sure whether you wanted to allow any random domain, but in case you want to allow, you can use this regex,

```
^(?:https?://(?:\w+\.)+\w+(?:/\S*)*|sc-domain:(?:\w+\.)+\w+)$
```

**[Regex Demo allowing any domain](https://regex101.com/r/PxmPum/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/7w3zbt/1) also would do that using two simple capturing groups that you can modify as you wish:

```
^((http|https)(:\/\/www.foo.com)(\/.*))|(sc-domain:www.foo.com)$
```

I have also added http, which you can remove it if it may be undesired.

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /^(((http|https)(:\/\/www.foo.com)(\/.*))|(sc-domain:www.foo.com))$/gm;
const str = `https://www.foo.com/
https://www.foo.com/bar/
sc-domain:www.foo.com
http://www.foo.com/
http://www.foo.com/bar/
`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Test with Python

You can simply test with Python and add the capturing groups that are desired:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^((http|https)(:\/\/www.foo.com)(\/.*))|(sc-domain:www.foo.com)$"

test_str = ("https://www.foo.com/\n"
    "https://www.foo.com/bar/\n"
    "sc-domain:www.foo.com\n"
    "http://www.foo.com/\n"
    "http://www.foo.com/bar/\n\n"
    "htps://www.foo.com/\n"
    "https:/www.foo.com/bar/\n"
    "sc-domain:www.foo.com/\n"
    "sc-domain:www.foo.com/bar\n"
    "scdomain:www.foo.com")

subst = "$1 $2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Edit

Based on [Pushpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102956/pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi)'s advice, you can use lookaround and simplify it to:

```
^((https?)(:\/\/www.foo.com)(\/.*))|(sc-domain:www.foo.com)$
```